# Problema con nullPointerException en servlet

Tags: java

Resulta que tengo el siguiente problema con un formulario y su respectivo servlet en JAVA, cuando completo el formulario y envio los datos por el form mediante un boton, al recibirlos en el servlet con el request.getParameter estos llegan como null (la verdad no tengo idea que puede ser ya que en otros proyectos similares funciona perfectamente).

**Formulario**

```
<!--Formulario --> 
    
    <div class="container mt-5">
               <form action="AgregarServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class=" col-md-5" >
            <div class="card">
               
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>Agregar Productos</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nom" class="form-conttrol"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Precio </label>
                        <input type="number" name="pre" class="form-conttrol"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Stock </label>
                        <input type="number" name="sto" class="form-conttrol"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Imagen </label>
                        <input type="file" name="foto" class="form-conttrol"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!--Select para TipoAlcohol-->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s5 input-field">            
                                <select name="TipoAlcoholSelect" id="TipoAlcoholSelectt" >                                                           
                                    <c:forEach items="${tipoA}" var="ta">                                                                                          
                                                <option value="${ta.id}" >${ta.tipo}</option>                                                                                                  
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </select>               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Select para TipoAlcohol--> 

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!--Select para Categorias-->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s5 input-field">            
                                <select name="Categorias" id="Categoriass" >                    
                                    <option value="">Categorias</option>
                                    <c:forEach items="${catego}" var="ca">                                                                                          
                                                <option value="${ca.id}" >${ca.nombre}</option>                                                                                                  
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </select>               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Select para Categorias-->    
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger " name="action" value="agregar">Agregar</button>
                </div>

            </div>    
      </form>  

    </div>


    <!--Formulario -->
```

**servlet**

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
switch(action)  {

case"cargarCombos":
List<TipoAlcohol> tipodealcohol = TipoAlcoholEJB.findAll();
List<Categoria> categoriaa = CategoriaEJB.findAll();
request.getSession().setAttribute("tipoA", tipodealcohol);
request.getSession().setAttribute("catego", categoriaa);
request.getRequestDispatcher("agregarProductos.jsp").forward(request, response);   
    break;
case"agregar":
    try {
        Alcohol al = new Alcohol();
        TipoAlcohol tal = new TipoAlcohol();
        Categoria cat = new Categoria();
        
        String nom = request.getParameter("nom");            
        int p = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pre"));      
        int s = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sto"));

        Part archivo = request.getPart("foto");//llamada al parámetro foto de mi formulario.
        String context = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("imagen"); //img es la carpeta que he creado en mi proyecto, dentro de la carpeta Web Content.
        String foto = Paths.get(archivo.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); 
        archivo.write(context + File.separator + foto); // Escribimos el archivo al disco duro del servidor.
        String UPLOAD_DIR = "uploads";
        String fotoName = UPLOAD_DIR + File.separator + foto;

        int tipoA = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("TipoAlcoholSelect"));
        tal.setId(tipoA);
        int Cat = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Categorias"));
        cat.setId(Cat);
        
        System.out.println(nom);
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(s);
        
        al.setDescripcion(nom);
        al.setPrecio(p);
        al.setStock(s);
        al.setImgRuta(fotoName);
        
        al.setTipoAlcoholID(tal);
        al.setCategoriaID(cat);
        AlcoholEJB.create(al);
        
        List<Alcohol>Copetes = AlcoholEJB.findAll();
        request.getSession().setAttribute("productos", Copetes);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Administrar.jsp").forward(request, response);   
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AgregarServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.err.print(ex);
    } catch (ServletException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AgregarServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.err.print(ex);
    }
    

    break;
 }
```

**error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Servlets.AgregarServlet.processRequest(AgregarServlet.java:56)
at Servlets.AgregarServlet.doPost(AgregarServlet.java:143)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

cabe destacar que la primera linea que apunta el error

```
at Servlets.AgregarServlet.processRequest(AgregarServlet.java:56)
```

segun yo no resalta nada importante(es el break del case anterior)

```
        break;
```

Les agradeceria mucho si me ayudan a encontrar alguna solucion, Gracias.

Comment: El servlet como lo tienes anotado ?? . Podria ser que falte el slash (/) antes de AgregaServlet en el form action . Podrias poner la clase servlet completa y podria ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: ¿`action` también llega en `null`?